# How do I make this div in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've designed the div below and I have no idea how to make it in bootstrap. I would like the div to be 10 columns wide and the images are svg images which are 64px wide and 48px tall. The text in the middle is the font Roboto from Google Fonts and is 20px in size. I would like the images and text to be vertically centered too.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVjA5.png)

My attempt: `

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center"> 
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"> 
         <img src="img/breath.svg" width="64" height="46.64" class="img-responsive" alt="Breath"> 
</div><!-- col-sm-1 --> 
<p>You have taken 500000 breaths</p> 
</div><!-- col-sm-10 --> 
</div><!-- row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach to this might be to use bootstraps flexbox display class `d-flex`. I've taken your code and put it into a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/VY0JBNTnwq). There's more information about flexbox and how to use it in the bootstrap documentation located [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

HTML with Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x48" alt="breath">
       span class="align-middle">You have taken 5000000 breaths</span>
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x48" alt="breath">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked it just needs more margin but I'll give that a shot myself